# Strange Vertical Bars appear when using LWJGL on Windows

Tags: java, windows, opengl, graphics, lwjgl

I'm writing a game in java that uses LWJGL's native OpenGL bindings to render the game graphics in OpenGL. When I run the game on Linux (tested on 2 different computers with different graphics cards), everything works fine. However, when I run the game on Windows, strange vertical 1-pixel-wide bars appear on the display.

Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

I tried this on three different Windows computers with different graphics cards, all of which had up-to-date drivers.

What's interesting is the bars appear in exactly the same location every time I run the program, even though the terrain generated is different every time.

I'm confused why these vertical bars are appearing. The code I use to render the terrain is

```
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// draw the terrain
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glColor3f(0F, 0F, 0F);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for (int x = 0; x < Constants.NUM_WIDE; x++) {
    glVertex2i(x, 0);
    glVertex2i(x, originalHeightMap[x]);
}
glEnd();

//draw a smooth line strip on top of the terrain to anti-alias it
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (int x = 0; x < Constants.NUM_WIDE; x++) {
    glVertex2i(x, originalHeightMap[x]);
}
glEnd();
```

This code should fill the entire width.

Another interesting fact is if you look closely, you should be able to see the smooth line strip on top of the terrain in places where the white bars are. This white-bars problem somehow removed the black lines that were part of the terrain but didn't remove the lines that anti-aliased the top.

I tried turning blending on and off when rendering the terrain, the same problem occurred in both cases.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem, or why it only occurs on windows?

Comment: What projection and modelview matrices do you use when drawng this? To me, this looks like some not pixel-exact mapping. Note that when you use something like glOrtho(0.0,width,...), the horizontal pixel centers are at 0.5, 1.5, ..., width-1.5, width-0.5, not at integral values.

Comment: @derhass I set up my OpenGL at the start with glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, Constants.NUM_WIDE, 0, Constants.NUM_HIGH, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

Where Constants.NUM_WIDE and NUM_HIGH are the size of my display canvas.

Comment: this seems to be exactly my point. You are not drawing at pixel centers (except you were correting for the offset via MODELVIEW). But lines should be draw at the pixel center in that case. It might be the case that the windows machine has MSAA enabled in the driver, so  such an effect is likely to occur, but it could also be some numerical instabilities as you are drawing exactly at pixel boundaries.

Comment: @derhass I seem to have fixed it with the stupid hack of just drawing with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, but do you have a suggested fix for how I set up OpenGL so this isn't a hack?

Comment: just try your line drawing code from above, but change the projection matrix to glOrtho(-0.5, (GLfloat)Constants.NUM_WIDE-0.5f, ...);

Comment: @derhass I changed the glOrtho, which did align the lines onto the pixels (I know because it fit the frame better on my Linux computer) but it didn't fix this annoying vertical bars problem. I think I'll stick to GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP in the meantime.